# Http exit status(as set by servlet) while trying to capture audio on browser

Tags: java, audio, glassfish, applet, capture

I am trying to capture audio by using https://github.com/mlni/microphone-on-the-web this. But when ı run it by using glassfish, it give an error like in the title.

```
 <b>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Sound recorder test</title>
 <style>
     body {
         background-color: #FEFFEF;
     }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Sound recorder test</h1>
 <object type="application/x-java-application" width="250" height="120">
     <param name="mayscript" value="true">
     <param name="archive" value="microphone-on-the-web-0.6-signed.jar">
     <param name ="code" value="ee.mattijagula.mikker.RecorderApplet">
     <param name="upload_url" value="upload.php" />
     <param name="upload_field_name" value="fail" />
     <param name="post_parameters" value="MAX_FILE_SIZE=20000000; 
   tx_fileupload_pi1[do_upload]=Saada fail!" />
     <param name="filename" value="vaikimisi_faili_nimi" />
     <param name="max_duration_seconds" value="120" />
     <param name="background_color" value="#FEFFEF" />
 </object>
 </body>
 </html>
 </b>
```

this is my html code, I am using GlassFish_Server 5.1 and jdk_1.8. What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that browsers now block Java applets or make it very difficult to enable them. The Java language has deprecated japplet in Java SE 9 and I think discontinued in Java SE 11. The code repository you are trying to use, also, is 9 years since its last update. IDK how recording is done (controversies exist about use in spying) these days. You will likely have to find another way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, ı dont know any other way to record audio and export it to server. I dont know javascript and most of the sample codes are in javascript. I only want to record audio and export it to server. If you have something like that, can you help me?

Comment: I would first try using the new Web Audio API. A quick search gave me the following url. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API But it does appear that this is going to require JavaScript.